# Corona native.showPopup not sharing image on facebbok (android)

Tags: android, facebook, lua, share, coronasdk

```
function listener:popup( event )
  -- my listener
end

native.showPopup( "social",
  {
    service = 'facebook',
    listener = listener,
    image = { filename="temp_img.jpg", baseDir=system.TemporaryDirectory},
  }
)
```

I have problem when trying to share an image on facebook from android. (IOS is working fine)

The problem is when the sharing popup shows up it doesn't have the image that i want to share attached.

Corona version: v2015.2646 ( I have tried with other versions)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The image table in the options table passed as the second argument of the native.showPopup function has to be a table containing sub tables with those two key values.

So change this:

```
image = { filename="temp_img.jpg", baseDir=system.TemporaryDirectory},
```

To this:

```
image = 
    { 
        {
            filename="temp_img.jpg", 
            baseDir=system.TemporaryDirectory
        },
        -- additional images if any
    }
```

You can check this at the official documentation site: [Corona SDK Social PopUp - showPopup()](https://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/CoronaProvider_native_popup_social/showPopup.html)